# regex: remove keyword(s) at start but not in all of the string

Tags: python, regex

A path name starts with one or two times the same folder name `pictures`. I need to remove these but keep any folders with the same name `pictures` later in the path. I came up with this solution:

```
import re
path_name = 'd:\pictures\pictures\hallo\pictures\\'
cleaned_path_name = re.sub(r'^pictures\\', '', re.sub(r'^.:\\pictures\\', '', path_name))
print(path_name)
print(cleaned_path_name)
```

```
d:\pictures\pictures\hallo\pictures\
hallo\pictures\
```

Is there a way to do this in one regex expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limited repetition should work here:

```
cleaned_path_name = re.sub(r'^.:\\(pictures\\){1,2}', '', path_name)
```

{1,2} means that the expression beforehand occurs at minimum once and at maximum twice.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot, although I am almost sure I have tried it! The regex pattern I was looking for is: `pattern = r'^[a-zA-Z]:\\(?:pictures\\){1,2}(.*)\\$'` to get the result in `re.search(pattern, path_name).group(1)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland: "It does not mean that the string may contain no more than three characters." -> I agree to this, but don't see why that should contradict my last sentence. I didn't write that the string may only contain up to three characters.

Comment: You are correct. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.subn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn) to limit the number of substitutions:

```
new_pathname, _ = re.subn(r'\bpictures\\', '', path_name, 1)
print(new_pathname)
```

---

```
d:\pictures\hallo\pictures\
```